# Save Rupee Symbol Directly to database

Tags: sql

Can anyone tell me how to save rupee symbol directly from textbox to the column of type `nvarchar` in database?

Because when I try to add rupee symbol it stored as `?` symbol.

Comment: API used? dbms used?

Comment: check the encoding of your database, what is it?

Comment: Have you tried insert with the literal U&'\20a8'

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your database but in most cases you need to make it unicode befor inserting by adding `N` at the beginning

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable(unicodeColumn)
VALUES(N'any unicode characters including rupee symbol')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
Create table foobar (that nvarchar(1))
Insert into foobar values (N'₹')

Select that
from foobar
```